# Rescale the secondary y axis got from twiny

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to add a secondary y axis whose ticks are rescaled from the original one. The rescaleY function in my code uses twiny to add the secondary axis, and then I set the ybound of the new axis and set the aspect ratio for it as well. The result shows correct correspondence between the left and right y axes, but the bounds are not correct.

WHAT I WANT:
The ybound of the left y axis to be (-0.5, 4.5) and the ybound of the right y axis to be (-5.0, 45.0).

WHAT I GET: The ybound of the left y axis is (-2, 6) and the ybound of the right y axis to be (-20, 60), i.e., with white stripes on top and at bottom of the actual plotting area.

This problem appears to show up only when the aspect ratio of the original plot is 'equal'. In this case, this is a result of the call to imshow (In contrast, if I use pcolormesh, everything looks fine; if I manually reset the aspect for the result of imshow, it is fine, too). You may also noticed that the on-screen print of the ybound are different from what you read from the image.

Anyone has an idea to fix this? Thanks.

The code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *

def rescaleY(ax=None,scaleY=1.0):
    '''
    Add an right-side y-axis whose ticks are 
    rescaled from that of ax by scaleY.
    '''
    if ax == None:
        ax = gca()
    x0,x1 = ax.get_xbound()
    y0,y1 = ax.get_ybound()
    axTwinX = ax.twinx()
    if ax.get_aspect() in ['equal',1.,1]:
        axTwinX.set_aspect(1./scaleY)
    axTwinX.set_ybound(y0*scaleY, y1*scaleY)
    #print axTwinX.get_xbound(),axTwinX.get_ybound()
    return axTwinX

xs = arange(10)
ys = arange(5)
x,y=meshgrid(xs,ys)
ax = gca()
ax.imshow(sin(x),origin='lower')

axTwinX = rescaleY(ax,10)

print ax.get_xbound(),ax.get_ybound(),ax.get_aspect()
print axTwinX.get_xbound(),axTwinX.get_ybound(),axTwinX.get_aspect()
savefig('rescaleY',bbox_inches='tight')
show()
```

The result command line output:

(-0.5, 9.5) (-0.5, 4.5) equal

(-0.5, 9.5) (-5.0, 45.0) 0.1

The result image:
[image: rescaleY]

Answer (score 1):

insert this under the line `ax.imshow(...)`

```
ax.set_aspect('auto')
```

This set's the aspect ratio so that it fits with the data to show.

Comment: Thank you for reply, M4rtini. Yes this should work (and I mentioned this in my post). However, I does want to force the aspect ratio to be "equal".